# Session variables are not cleared when the page is refreshed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have declared session variables in my web application.When i close the web application through tab i.e when the tab of chrome is closed the session variables are not getting cleared.But when i close the entire window the session variables are getting cleared.
Is there any way wherein i can clear the session variables when the page is refreshed?

Comment: Have you looked into using Viewstate instead of Session variables?

Comment: try for `Session.Abandon()`..

Comment: 'Session' retains its state for as long as the browser is open, or when it is set to expire.  Closing the tab does not abandon the session.

Comment: this problem is having only in chrome or in other browser as well..

Comment: I cannot use Viewstate as i want to use the variables from one page to other.I know that the session variables can be cleared by using Session.Abandon(),but the question is i want it to be cleared on page refresh.Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

I think you shold allow the user to decide this, by calling `Session.Abandon()` from a Logout button/link.  As a user, you may not want your session to expire just because you have closed the tab.

You can also use `Session.Clear()` to clear down session data, but this does not remove that session.  If you want to clear data on page refresh, then you could call this in the `Page_Load` event. **Note**, `Session.RemoveAll()` will do the same thing.

Take a look at [HttpSessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.aspx) for more information, explaining the above methods.

If you want the session to expire if no activity takes place, then take a look at the [timeout option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout.aspx) - this could be useful if the data is personal/sensitive and you would want the session to expire on a public machine, i.e. Internet Cafe.

Answer (score 1):

Use Session.Clear() in **Page_Load**.Sessions will be cleared when refreshing page.

Answer (score 0):

Try for [Session.Abandon()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524310%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method.

or

[Session.Clear()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.clear.aspx)

I think you need to use any of the method inside your `Page_Load` method.

Answer (score 0):

Session.[Clear](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.clear.aspx) - Removes all keys and values from the session-state collection.

Session.[Abandon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524310.aspx) - removes all the objects stored in a Session.

Use this in your Page_Load event